# Google Analytics API Create New Property

Tags: php, api, properties, insert, google-analytics

The issue I'm having is when I try and insert a new web property using the Google Analytics Api I'm getting the error:
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Your project does not have access to this feature."

This is even when I use the page:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert

Has anyone being able to successfully create a new web property and return its tracking code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time that this question was written, write operations were still in beta.  At the time, it was required to request access to the beta. From the GA documentation at the time:

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete,
>   patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is
>   currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're
>   interested in using these features,  [request access to the beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtProfileGuide#limits).

After applying for the beta, developers were unlikely to hear back from GA, but after 24 hours it normally worked.

Comment: If you click on the link you can see that it still states that you need to apply for Beta access.   So yes it is still in beta

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for create property api solution for GA 4 then you could try as follows :

```
const property = {"account":"accounts/123","displayName":"displayName","currencyCode":"USD","propertyType":"PROPERTY_TYPE_ORDINARY","timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles","parent":"accounts/123","industryCategory":"INDUSTRY_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED"};

        // Imports the Admin library
    const {AnalyticsAdminServiceClient} = require('@google-analytics/admin').v1alpha;

    // Instantiates a client
    const adminClient = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient({keyFilename: credentialFile});

    async function callCreateProperty() {
        // Construct request
        const request = {
            property,
        };

        // Run request
        const response = await adminClient.createProperty(request);
        console.log(response);
    }
```

More details can be found under

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties#Property

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/create